# How to pass a token value to QGIS processing modeler?

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing

There are various places in the Processing modeler where I would like to pass the value of a variable.
We're iterating through a bunch of features in an input layer. After the processing, we will have a new shapefile per input feature.
I want to name each of the new shapefiles based on a value in the new attribute table...this gives me a unique name per new shapefile.
For example, using the Field Calculator, We run a simple math operation and store the result in a new result field.
We can create a new OutputVector for the calculated result, and I want to use an attribute table value to create the name, like:
myResultVector-%SOMECOLUMNLABEL

Where SOMECOLUMNLABEL is the column that contains the attribute of interest, and myResultVector is a nice namespace.
If I could name each of the output vectors uniquely, I could save them all in a single folder for future processing.